# DropDownListFor failed in partial view due to expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 community edition for ASP.net MVC project testing,
Here is my simple model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [UIHint("EnumList")]
    public TestState State { get; set; }
}

public enum TestState
{
    eNone,
    eNew,
    eFinished,
}
```

Here is a generic html - EnumList.cshtml

```
@model Enum

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, Enum.GetValues(Model.GetType()).OfType<Enum>()
    .Select(m =>
    {
        string enumVal = Enum.GetName(Model.GetType(), m);
        return new SelectListItem()
        {
            Selected = (Model.ToString() == enumVal),
            Text = enumVal,
            Value = enumVal
        };
    })
)
```

it works fine if below is used in Test view which accepts TestModel as model.

```
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

However when I try to use above EnumList.cshtml via specific action as below:

```
@Html.Action("Enum", new { pState = Model.State });     <-- used in View html

// below action will be called by above method
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult Enum(TestState? pState)
{
    return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/EnumList.cshtml", pState.HasValue ? pState.Value : TestState.eNone);
}
```

I got following errors:

*Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: name*

below is from the stack trace:

*[ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: name]
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.SelectInternal(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata metadata, String optionLabel, String name, IEnumerable`1 selectList, Boolean allowMultiple, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +589
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression, IEnumerable`1 selectList, String optionLabel, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +95
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression, IEnumerable`1 selectList) +60
   ASP._Page_Views_Shared_EditorTemplates_EnumList_cshtml.Execute() in c:\visual studio 2015\Projects\Test\Test1\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\EnumList.cshtml:3
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +105*

It works if above DropDownListFor() is called directly in Test view with changes like "m => m.State", so I believe this error to do with "m => m", but what is the correct expression then?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of `@Html.Action("Enum", new { pState = Model.State });` use `@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.State,"EnumList")`

Comment: There are way too many questions about DropDownLists on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your usage of [DropDownListFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%7BSystem.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem%7D%29) is wrong (from the MSDN description of DropDownListFor helpers ):

> Returns an HTML select element for each **property** in the object that is represented by the specified expression using the specified list items.

You are using it for the model itself and not for model properties!

**Explanation why your approach works with view which accepts TestModel as model and doesn't work as a separate partial view:**

By default editor templates generate id and name properties for it's inputs as a combination of parent prefix(see examples) with the current model property name. For example when you use `TestModel` as the main model for your view and the use `@Html.EditorForModel()`, the name and the id of you select will be `State` :

`<select name="State" id="State">....`

If for example your `TestModel` is a property of `ParentTestModel`:

```
public class ParentTestModel
{
    public TestModel TestModelProperty {get;set;}
}
```

Then your editor template will be rendered as

```
<select name="TestModelProperty.State" id="TestModelProperty_State">...
```

When you render a template as a partial view with `Enum` as model both

1. parent prefix is null - in general partial views don't preserve those prefixes and in this particular case there is no prefix at all because its a top model
   and
2. property name is null - because of `m => m` expression which basically doesn't select any property

so `FullHtmlFieldName` is `null`. So this code (internal implementation of SelectList helpers ) throws an exception:

```
private static MvcHtmlString SelectInternal(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata metadata,
            string optionLabel, string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, bool allowMultiple,
            IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
        {
            string fullName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(MvcResources.Common_NullOrEmpty, "name");
            } ...
```